# Tkinter Button command function doesn't perform its task

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

#Windows
logWin = Tk()
mainWin = Tk()
srchWin = Tk()
NTWin = Tk()

#Variables
userName="123"
password="123"
logFail = ""
userBox = Entry(logWin)
passBox = Entry(logWin)
EU = userBox.get()
EP = passBox.get()

#General Window
mainWin.withdraw()
srchWin.withdraw()
NTWin.withdraw()

#Command
def loginCmd():
    if EU == userName and EP == password:
        print ("hello")
    else:
        print("no")


#Login Window
logWin.title("Login")
logWin.geometry("200x70")

userBox.grid(row=0,column=1)
passBox.grid(row=1,column=1)

userLbl = Label(logWin,text="Username:")
userLbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
passLbl = Label(logWin,text="Password:")
passLbl.grid(row=1,column=0)
failLbl = Label(logWin,text=logFail)
failLbl.grid(row=2,column=0)

logBtn = Button(logWin,text="Login",command=loginCmd)
logBtn.grid(row=2,column=1)


mainloop()
```

I am trying to create a program that requires you to login however my `if` statement in my `def` of the command doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

[screenshot of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN5m0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it to work, you need to get value when you click the button not when the textbox is initialized. Therefore, if you change the login function to the following, your program should function as expected.

```
def loginCmd():
    if userBox.get() == userName and passBox.get() == password:
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("no")
```